# How do I get render to work with nested controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partials, nested-controls

These are my routes:

```
resources :auctions do
  resources :bids
end
```

I have the `auctions#show` view with a form for bids:

```
= form_for [@auction, @bid] do |form|
  = form.input :maximum
  = form.button :submit
```

This of course `POST` to `auctions/:auction_id/bids`.

I have this `bids#create` action:

```
def create
  #...some_logic...
  if @bid.save
    #...happy_face...
  else
    # See Below
  end
end
```

In this "if the bid didn't save logic" I have:

```
render 'auctions/show'
```

This should (and does) try to render the `app/views/auctions/show.html.erb` but I get this error:

```
Missing partial bids/info-panel, application/info-panel with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
    * "app/views"
    * "gems/devise-2.0.4/app/views"
```

Obviously this is a problem!
It's looking in `app/views/bids` instead of `app/views/auctions` for the partials.

How do I make the context be `app/views/auctions` for those partials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an error condition, why dont you redirect to auctions/show action instead of rendering its template.
You can pass error metadata with your redirect, so that auctions/show action knows that its an error state and renders the form accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I heavily considered that (and I think I'll probably do it), but the app I'm dealing with doesn't make it that easy :( Marking yours as the answer anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
<%= render :partial => "auctions/info-panel" %>
```

If you don't include the leading directory, it assumes the current directory.

Comment: I'm not willing to change ALL the partial calls in `app/views/auctions/show.html.erb` to specify the auctions directory. That seems silly and very not DRY.

Comment: In addition, any *_path methods wont work as they're in the context of `auctions/:auction_id/bids` route.